# Read Date in a file and add one day

Tags: bash, shell, date

I want to read a file which contain a date and rewrite this file with plus one day
I have this command line :

```
date --date=$(cat /parm/control.date) "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "tomorrow" > control.date
```

When I run many times this command it return tomorrow of the current date ..

Thank you :)

Comment: This may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/linux-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-virtual-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date --date="$(< /dz-ceibo/applis/db5/parm/control.date) + 1 day" "+%Y-%m-%d"
```

Using bash's `$(< file)` instead of `cat`